# Affect some logic lists using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I am trying to change the loop to Java streams.

For example,

```
interface Logic {
    int apply(int value);
}

public class AddOneLogic implements Logic {
    @Override
    public int apply(int value) {
        return value + 1;
    }
}

public class AddTwoLogic implements Logic {
    @Override
    public int apply(int value) {
        return value + 2;
    }
}
```

Using a loop to apply a `Logic` looks like

```
List<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<>();
logics.add(new AddOneLogic());
logics.add(new AddTwoLogic());

int init = 1;
```

I want to change to streams below. Is there any better way to do it?

```
int result = init;
for (Logic logic : logics) {
    result = logic.apply(result);
}
```

Comment: Lambdas would be elegant.  These Logic classes aren't necessary.  Hopefully they're trivial examples of what you really want to do.

Comment: Lambda is not a good candidate for solving this problem. What you have is better. Just keep it.

Comment: if only change loop to Stream when it used. <br> logics.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.apply(init)));

Answer (score 1):

As @duffymo mentioned in the comments, these classes aren't particularly useful and they could be replaced with `Function<Integer, Integer>`s and lambda expressions to define them.

In that case, you may want to reduce a list/stream of `Function`s by `Function::andThen`,

```
Function<Integer, Integer> addOneFunction = i -> i + 1;
Function<Integer, Integer> addTwoFunction = i -> i + 2;

Function<Integer, Integer> function = 
    Stream.of(addOneFunction, addTwoFunction)
          .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
```

so you would get a composed function to work with

```
Integer result = function.apply(init);
// ((1 + 1) + 2) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Stream` and  `AtomicInteger` and `getAndSet(int)` method as below,

```
 AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger(1);
 logics.stream().forEach(ele-> result.getAndSet(ele.apply(result.get())));
// result = ((1+1)+2)=4
```

Better option would be to use `Function`,

```
Function<Integer, Integer> addOne = i -> i + 1;
Function<Integer, Integer> addTwo = i -> i + 2;

List<Function<Integer, Integer>> logics = new ArrayList<>();
logics.add(addOne);
logics.add(addTwo);

AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger(1);
logics.stream().forEach(ele-> result.getAndSet(ele.apply(result.get())));
```

You can even avoid logics list and use `andThen` method as below,

```
Function<Integer, Integer> add = addOne.andThen(addTwo);
result = add.apply(1);
```

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned: The intention behind the question *might* be distorted by the attempt to simplify the question so that it can be posted here. The `Logic` interface does not really make sense, because it could be replaced with an `IntUnaryOperator`.

<sup>**Not** with a `Function<Integer, Integer>` - that's a different thing!</sup>

But I'll (also) make some assumptions when trying to answer the question:

- The `Logic` interface is merely a placeholder for an interface that has to be retained in its current form
- Several `Logic` instances can sensibly be combined in order to yield an new `Logic`
- The goal is *not* to "apply streams for the streams sake", but to create *sensible*, *usable* classes and methods (and it's a pity that this is worth mentioning...)

If this is the case, then I'd suggest creating a `CombinedLogic` class that simply offers a method for combining several `Logic` objects to create the combined one.

<sup>It could also be a concrete class that internally stores a `List<Logic>`. This might be handy in order to modify a combined logic later, as in `combinedLogic.setElement(42, new OtherLogic());`. But a public class with a modifiable state should be thought through carefully...</sup>

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CombinedLogicExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<>();
        logics.add(new AddOneLogic());
        logics.add(new AddTwoLogic());
        Logic combined = CombinedLogic.of(logics);

        // Alternatively:
        // Logic logic1 = new AddOneLogic();
        // Logic logic2 = new AddTwoLogic();
        // Logic combined = CombinedLogic.of(logic1, logic2);

        int init = 1;
        int result = combined.apply(init);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

class CombinedLogic {

    static Logic of(Logic... logics) {
        return of(Arrays.asList(logics));
    }

    static Logic of(Iterable<? extends Logic> logics) {
        return a -> {
            int result = a;
            for (Logic logic : logics) {
                result = logic.apply(result);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
}

interface Logic {
    int apply(int value);
}

class AddOneLogic implements Logic {
    @Override
    public int apply(int value) {
        return value + 1;
    }
}

class AddTwoLogic implements Logic {
    @Override
    public int apply(int value) {
        return value + 2;
    }
}
```